# How I to parse includes with bison/flex?

Tags: c++11, bison, flex-lexer

I would like to do the following example by parsing linker scripts

example.ld

```
MEMORY 
{
  INCLUDE example_include.ld 
}
```

example_include.ld

```
rom   : ORIGIN = 0, LENGTH = 256K
```

I have found some code which could do this, but it is c flex/bison and I use c++ flex / bison.

I ve figured out that I can use `yyFlexLexer lexer;`
which provides me: `yy_create_buffer()` and so on ...

This is the code I ve found in binutils/ld/ldlex.l. Maybe it could help me.

```
void
lex_push_file (FILE *file, const char *name, unsigned int sysrooted)
{
    if (include_stack_ptr >= MAX_INCLUDE_DEPTH)
    {
      einfo ("%F:includes nested too deeply\n");
    }
  file_name_stack[include_stack_ptr] = name;
  lineno_stack[include_stack_ptr] = lineno;
  sysrooted_stack[include_stack_ptr] = input_flags.sysrooted;
  include_stack[include_stack_ptr] = YY_CURRENT_BUFFER;

  include_stack_ptr++;
  lineno = 1;
  input_flags.sysrooted = sysrooted;
  yyin = file;
  yy_switch_to_buffer (yy_create_buffer (yyin, YY_BUF_SIZE));
}
```

My problem is that, I do not find a good example or documentation, how to use the c++ bison / flex? For example, I cannot use `yyin`, because it is protected and not public.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just recursively call the parser, passing it the file to be parsed. The precise details about how you communicate the environmental information (that is, the state of the parse) from the outer parser to the inner parser will depend heavily on the nature of your internal data structures, so I'm not even going to venture a guess. If all you're doing is building an AST (which is almost always the best solution even though it never seems attractive at first sight), then you won't have to do anything other than have the parser return the AST to its caller when it successfully parses a file.

The parser (or its manager) will generally create a new Lexer object to scan the provided input file; since the C++ scanners are fully reentrant, the coexistence of the two lexers creates no difficulties. This avoids using the buffer stack, and is generally a much cleaner solution.

This avoids a classic problem with handling "includes" in bison/flex parsers, which is that a naive solution allows syntactic context to leak out of the included file back into the including file. If the included file contains an unterminated block (or unterminated comment), that syntactic context might continue to be active at the end of the include, leading to unintuitive and often misleading error messages. The recursive strategy will instead trigger a syntax error at the end of the included file, which will also make error recovery easier.

Disclaimer: I'm really not a fan of the C++ interfaces for the scanners and parsers generated by flex and bison. Maybe someday I'll change my mind; I freely admit that it might just be intellectual laziness. In any case, aside from a few toys, the only parsers I've built use the C APIs, even when I write the actions in C++ (which I often do). So I'm not providing any sample code here, but I don't think that it's particularly difficult.

Comment: I followed the documentation and did it that way. with BEGIN(incl). It still very loose and I may ask again here more specific.